# android AsyncTask error with Progressdialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a problem with my progress Dialog and I can't find what Im doing wrong.
When I press the button Localize, my code does the new AsyncTask and the progressDialog start, but finally it stop itself and display an error. I think the problem is because is too long what it has to do. The error is this :

An error ocurred while executing doInBackground()

I think the problem is with publishProgress() but I dont know how and where use it.

Here my code:

```
public class GPSLocation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{  
    boolean running =true;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {  
        super.onPreExecute(); 
        pd = new ProgressDialog(Configuracion.this);
        pd.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                pd.cancel();  
            }
        });
        longitude=0;
        latitude =0;
        getLonLat();
        pd.setCancelable(true);
        pd.setMessage("Getting GPS Location...");
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pd.show();
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        pd.setProgress(1);
        // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {  
        pd.dismiss(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {  
        boolean isDataSubmitted = false;
        while(!isDataSubmitted)
        {  
            if(longitude !=0 && latitude!=0)
            { 
                isDataSubmitted = true;
                Log.d("LONGITUD", ""+longitude);
                Log.d("LATITUDE", ""+latitude);
                longitud.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
                latitud.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
            }  
        } 

        return null;    
    } 
}
```

This is out of GPSLocation class, and is called from Localize.setOnclicklistener(this);

```
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        if (v.getId() == R.id.localiza){

            new GPSLocation().execute();
             }
         }
```

This method here :

```
  public void getLonLat(){

        LocationManager milocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener milocListener = new MiLocationListener();
        if (milocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            milocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,milocListener);

        }else if (milocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            milocManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, milocListener);
        }

    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: "I have a problem with my progress Dialog" What is the problem?

Comment: You can't change any UI element(s) in a background thread like `doInBackground`. You'll have to return something to `onPostExecute` and `setText` from there.

Comment: These: `longitud.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));` & `latitud.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));` are your issues. Comment them out and run and I bet you'll lose the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the method `.setText()` in your doInBackground(). It will lead to an error. Instead you can settext in `onPostExecute()`

Chnage your code to

```
@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
{  
    pd.dismiss(); 
    longitud.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
    latitud.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {  
    boolean isDataSubmitted = false;
    while(!isDataSubmitted)
    {  
        if(longitude !=0 && latitude!=0)
        { 
            isDataSubmitted = true;
            Log.d("LONGITUD", ""+longitude);
            Log.d("LATITUDE", ""+latitude);
        }  
    } 
    return null;    
}
```

Comment: I think this one is right, for further info for the OP you must run the UI change on the UI thread. In async task it can be done in onPreExecute(),onProgressUpdate(Progress...), and onPostExecute(Result)

Comment: @Asok, I know the answer. That's y i post it here. I just want to help the user. But nothing more else...

Comment: @Ramkiran If that is the case then the answer is already there, no need. With your reputation you should have closed and referenced one of the thousands of duplicates. Or +1'd my comment.

Comment: @Asok, in future if some body have seen this page, Generally the visitors must see the answers then the posted comments.So if you know the answer post it as answer not like comment

Comment: Answers should be posted to a question, not just comments @asok ... if you thought your comment was the answer, you should've answered.

Comment: @mikebabcock A little late to the game. +1 for replicating others comments. FYI, I use comments to troubleshoot possible causes for OP's issues prior to publishing an answer, there could be, and have often been, more than one reason for the OP's troubles. Plus the original question did not contain an error explanation, my comment was a mere guess at resolution at the time. I am not here for Kudos in the form of reputation or bickering in comments. If you're browsing old SO Q's to make comments such as the one you made above then feel free to chat me and we can discuss how I don't satisfy you.